# Does werkzeug support concurrent requests?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, wsgi, werkzeug

This question may already be answered but I didn't find any good answers. I've read that flask and werkzeug are both single threaded and synchronous but I just wrote a simple app with a route that responds after 10 seconds and one that responds instantly, I called the heavy one and then called the light one, the heavy one doesn't seem to be blocking the other, but I noticed the lighter request takes a few hundred more milliseconds when I call it while the heavy one is being processed, is werkzeug creating a separate process for the light one and are those extra milliseconds because of process overhead?

Comment: Werkzeug itself is a WSGI utility library for Python, and it doesn't directly handle concurrency. But it might be you're running your project via `gunicorn` workers or enabled threading in flask `app.run(threaded=True)`. it would be better to share your code for better insight.